# how to take .csv file as an input

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, csv

This my code where I take input as a sentence and predict the next word from the given corpus.
but my problem is I want to take a .csv file as an input and iterate through line by line and save the results in another .csv file

```
def takeInput():
    cond = False
    #take input
    while(cond == False):
        sen = input('Enter the string\n')
        sen = removePunctuations(sen)
        temp = sen.split()
        if len(temp) < 3:
            print("Please enter atleast 3 words !")
        else:
            cond = True
            temp = temp[-3:]
    sen = " ".join(temp)
    return sen


    input_sen = takeInput()
    word_choice = chooseWords(input_sen, bi_prob_dict, tri_prob_dict, quad_prob_dict)
    prediction = PredictiontheRes(input_sen, bi_dict, tri_dict, quad_dict, vocab_dict,token_len, word_choice, param)
    print('Word Prediction:',prediction)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use an argument parser - example below - and add a flag like -c to denote a csv file name, and not the file itself.

You would then have to write the logic to your needs. If the -c flag is present, check that the file exist and use a csv parser library - below as well - and iterate over the file.

argparse* - https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

csv* - https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

* if you're using Python 2.x change the link to point to 2, or consider using 3.

There are great code examples in the provided links.

[edit] - minimal example

```
import csv
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('csv')
parser.add_argument('csv')
args = parser.parse_args()

if len( sys.argv ) > 1:
  with open( args.csv ) as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    with open( args.csv+'output.csv', 'w') as outputCsvFile:
      writer = csv.writer(outputCsvFile, delimiter=',')
      for line in reader:
        processedLine = ['|'] + line + ['|']
        #process line
        writer.writerow( processedLine )
```

If you call this script like this:
`python script.py myCsv.csv`
Then the script will process the file 'myCsv.csv', process it, and then write 'myCsv.csvoutput.csv'

Comment: @wrinkledcheee... thanks for the links  but still i am not able to find the solution

Comment: rather than taking input a sentence i want to take .csv file as an input and iterate through every line of csv file

Comment: Added minimal example